# get the main form from another process

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 processed 1 receiver and one dispacther

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IDispacther
{
    private Action<string> m_action;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OnData(Action<string> action)
    {
        m_action = action;
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        m_action?.Invoke("Hello from dispacther");
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

simple , the dispacther just sends back data after a second

the interface is only getting the action

```
public interface IDispacther
{
    void OnData(Action<string> action);
}
```

The receiver main form looks like so:

```
    public ReceiverForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        startProcess();
        base.OnLoad(e);

    }

    private void startProcess()
    {
        string processName = "DispatcherEventTester.exe";
        var process  = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = processName;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForInputIdle();
        var container = Control.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
        IDispacther dispacter = .... //What should be here?

    }
```

I dont know how to get Form1 from the dispacther.exe that implements `IDispatcher`  from the mainwindowhandler - I know there is a way but i forgot

Comment: You can't just get a reference to something in another process and use it as it would be in the same process. You need a proper IPC mechanism for interop.

Comment: For inter-process communication (IPC) on a single windows machine you can use named pipes. In all other cases you should think about using a REST communication.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74982688/namaed-pipe-throws-exception-after-few-connections - changed to this